# Aggregating for different conditions

Tags: sql, presto

I have a window func as below:

```
select d.Name as Department, a. Name as Employee, a.sum(salary) 
from ( select e.*, dense_rank() over (partition by DepartmentId order by Salary desc) as DeptPayRank 
from Employee e 
) a 
join Department d
on a. DepartmentId = d. Id 
where DeptPayRank =1 
group by 1,2
```

If I want to also take the min of all salary the `DepPayRank = 3` can I add to this query or not possible?

Comment: Please add some sample data with your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Test:

```
SELECT d.Name AS Department, 
       a.Name AS Employee, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DeptPayRank = 1 THEN salary END),
       MIN(CASE WHEN DeptPayRank = 3 THEN salary END)
FROM ( SELECT e.*, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DepartmentId ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS DeptPayRank 
       from Employee e 
     ) a 
JOIN Department d ON a.DepartmentId = d.Id 
GROUP BY 1,2
/* HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN DeptPayRank = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 */
```